# How does one treat censored data in SAS?

Tags: regression, missing-data

I have some censored data and I'm not sure how to deal with it in my regression analysis. The study was not a time series and all examples I've seen in SAS have been in the context of survival analysis. All data came from a survey or biological samples. Should I count it as missing data? Thank you!

Comment: Which variables are censored--the response or the explanatory variables? (To see why censored data should not be considered missing, suppose you were assaying animal tissue for arsenic and had 1,000 samples, of which 950 were nondetects (at a limit of 1 ppt, say) and the rest were around 1 - 10 ppt.  Those 950 nondetects make it clear the mean arsenic in the population is likely less than 1 and cannot be much greater than 1. By treating them as missing you would grossly overestimate the mean population because you would be basing your estimate only on the (relatively few) detected values.)

Comment: It's the response variable. It's a pilot study with about 70 observations but about 10 of those 70 have censored data.

Comment: Sometimes this can be handled by simply re-defining your population.  For example, if you are looking at length of stay in a hospital, and you have censored data due to deaths, sometimes the simplest approach, is to redefine the population in your study as length of stay among patients discharged alive.

Comment: These might also be worth taking a look at:  http://www.ms.uky.edu/~mai/sta635/millerhalpern82.pdf
and
http://www.jstor.org/stable/1268280?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents

Answer (score 0):

You could use Tobit type of analysis. Here is a link to example in SAS proc qlim.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_qlim_sect034.htm

Comment: This is a good solution, but some explanation of what it is and what assumptions it makes would be highly desirable.